# show / Hide text in React Native , time out, gradient

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a page that basically is supposed  to process some back end work and then push on another screen.

This Page should have some text appearing as soon as the page renders that says "submitting your info" then do the backend call, and then the text disappears, and then the whole page performs a push for another screen.

I am confused how to do that !!

This is the render part of the page

```
render(){
 return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Image style={styles.container} resizeMode="cover" source=
 {require('/workingonit.png')}> 
      <View style={styles.backdropView}>
        <Text style={styles.headline}>Submitting your info</Text>
      </View>
    </Image>                        
  </View>
)
}
```

I know its something to do with settimeout? or interval?

Sorry I am new to JS and react native .

Answer (score 1):

This example will toggle (hide/show) the text every time you click on the TouchableOpacity by updating the state. You can then, add whatever logic you want as a callback when the state gets updated.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export default class DummyPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isTextVisible: false
  }

  toggleText() {
    this.setState({isTextVisible: !this.state.isTextVisible}, () => {
      // do some logic here
    })
  }

  renderText() {
    if (this.state.isTextVisible) {
      return(
        <Text>this is a random text</Text>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleText}>
          <Text>Show Text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {this.renderText()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This should work for your API call too. Instead of updating the state with onPress, you can do it when the communication with the backend starts and hide it again when you want to push the user to another screen.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond, How do I show the Text slowly though? like a gradient?